# Batch file to delete files from users on network

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file, delete-directory

I want the batch file to ask for Serial number and username and delete two specific folders from users profile. I made this but it seems to want to delete `*.*` from folder I am running it from.

```
@echo off

set /p serial="Enter Serial: "

set /p username="Enter Username: "

del *.* \\%serial%\C$\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
del *.* 
\\%serial%\C$\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations
pause
```

Comment: an asterisk denotes *italics*. To show asterisks, you must surround them in backticks for `inline code`. It's the thing to the left of the 1 on the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry when I say * . * I mean using it as a wildcard to delete everything there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next approach with basic checking all user's input:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

:inputServer
set "serial="
set /p "serial=Enter Serial: "
if not defined serial goto :endlocal
pushd "\\%serial%\C$\"
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo wrong server name "\\%serial%"
  goto :inputServer
)

:inputUser
set "_username="
set /p "_username=Enter Username: "
if not defined _username goto :endstack
cd "\users\%_username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo wrong user name "%_username%" or path
  echo "\\%serial%\C$\users\%_username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
  goto :inputUser
)

dir AutomaticDestinations\*.*
dir CustomDestinations\*.*

:endstack
popd

:endlocal
pause
```

Replace `dir` with `del /Q` no sooner than debugged.

[Resource for `PUSHD` - `POPD` pair](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html):

> When a `UNC` path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive
>   map and will then use that new drive.  The temporary drive letters are
>   allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if `Z:` is free it will be
>   used first.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! I learned so much from you all on this thread, now I can figure out why it works and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @supeg My pleasure. Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) if you find that it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that did not know you could do that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

c$ is administrator hiding ressources, you can't access to it without login

If you want to connect to network share on the remote computer, use this:
net use * \servername\sharename

Comment: I would be running the command with my admin creds. I will change the syntax and see if that helps. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `del` command does not allow to separate the file mask from the path where the files to delete are stored, so you need to use

```
del /q "\\%serial%\C$\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*.*"
del /q "\\%serial%\C$\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*.*"
```

The added quotes will prevent problems with paths that include spaces and the `/q` switch will avoid the security confirmation to delete the all the files in the indicated folder.

Comment: That did not work... it asks to delete wherever the file is run http://puu.sh/jWhfM.jpg

Comment: @supeg, just add a `/q` switch to the `del` command to avoid the question. Code updated

Comment: Sorry but it asks to delete wherever the file is run I mean it trys to delete the folder it is run from and not the remote dir I am trying to delete from

Comment: @supeg, silly question, but, have you changed the two lines that are deleting files? The indicated behaviour in answer applies to both lines.

Comment: do you mean the two file paths? Cause they are different at the very end.

Comment: @supeg, answer updated with the two commands changed. Yes, both are different at the end, but the command to run needs to be adapted in the same way

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the @echo off untill your code is working so you can see what's happening, then add some echo to see what is stored in the variable that you're using. After that try with DIR instead of DEL so it list the file that match your criteria.

```
REM    @echo off

set /p serial="Enter Serial: "
Echo %serial%
pause

set /p username="Enter Username: "
echo %username%
pause
dir \\%serial%\C$\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*.*
dir \\%serial%\C$\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*.*
pause
```